# Outlook 2013, and Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-excel-2007

Currently when clicking on an .xls or .xlsx file it opens in Excel 2007 fine. 
However when clicking on a .xlsx attachment in Outlook 2013 it opens in Excel 2013.

Is there a way to force Excel Attachments recieved in Outlook 2013 to open in Excel 2007.

Comment: Just download the attachment first then use Excel 2007 to open it manually. (Or, the drastic solution, uninstall Excel 2013)

Answer (score 0):

Outlook does not establish which program to open a file with. It simply references whatever Windows has set for the default application. I would ensure that your default program is indeed the version of Excel you want.  Your computer may have changed the default to 2013 once you installed it since it is the newest.

To change the default program, right click on one of your excel files with the extension you want to change, click open with.. click choose default program.. Check "Always use the selected program to open this kind of file", select the correct Excel version, and then click ok and it should be set.

Comment: Hi

I've already done the all this, and as I state above, when open an excel file saved on Desktop, or in a windows folder it opens in 2007. Only when clicking on an excel file in an email attachment (when using Outlook 2013) does it open in Excel 2013